# SimpleDateFormat returns always the same result

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I have a strange problem. I have this method, which should generate a Date out of the name of a directory.

```
private Date getSubfolderDate(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YY");
    Date date;
    try {
        date = parser.parse(name);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return null;
    }
    return date;
}
```

it returns for String name = "17-06-12": "Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 
2012"

and for String name = "18-06-12": "Mon Jan 02 00:00:00 CET 2012"

Why?

Later i am comparing these with the compareTo(Date xy) and it returns 0, so it has to be the same.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your format is also incorrect it should be `dd-MM-yy` (for 17-06-12), To tracedown the issue check the catch block with `printStackTrace()`

**Also**

`SimpleDateFormat` parses date from String the resultant Date will invoke toString() that have fixed format

So if you wish to print formatted date again you need to use `simpleDateFormat.format(dateInstance)`

`Date` class doesn't have any property that holds the format to be printed in `toString()`

Comment: Why are you referring to toString()

Comment: While printing date in System.out.println(dateInstance); it will invoke dateInstance.toString() and so the output

Comment: I read the dates from eclipse....i have never called System.out.println(dateInstance);

but the compareTo method also produces 0

Comment: the lower case was the answer... I have read the doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html
but i thought the lower case y is an upper case Y :)

Comment: But there comes al little off topic question.....I have also a code which generates me the folder
Why was it working there?

Answer (score 3):

I tried this code:

```
static Date getSubfolderDate(File file) {
  String name = file.getName();
  SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
  Date date;
  try {
    date = parser.parse(name);
  } catch (ParseException e) {
    return null;
  }
  return date;
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println(getSubfolderDate(new File("17-06-12")));
  System.out.println(getSubfolderDate(new File("18-06-12")));
}
```

It prints

```
Sun Jun 17 00:00:00 CEST 2012
Mon Jun 18 00:00:00 CEST 2012
```

Comment: Yeah the Upper case Y was the problem

Comment: However, the code you provide did not produce the output you posted; it threw an exception that stated `Illegal pattern character 'Y'` This might be telling me that there is bad exception handling at work in your code. The best way to handle exceptions is not to handle them, except for wrapping checked exceptions into a `RuntimeException` and rethrowing.

Comment: The problem is that there are folders which are named after dates and folders who are not.....date == null is later used to indentify whether it is named after a date, which will be treated differently than the others.
Normally the exceptions are desired

Comment: I didn't have that exception in mind, but the exception I mentioned just now -- the one thrown by `new SimpleDateFormat`. This is not covered by the try-block in the code you posted, and apparently you didn't see it.

Comment: the method is surrounded by a try/catch with the catch of a "normal" Exception. I have done this because nearly all the other code is either IO or my methods, which are throwing the standard exception....
but the catch should open an JOptionPane o.O